# How to retrieve all changed folders from the root public folder via EWS?

Tags: outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I need to get all public folders when a user changes permissions or items in a folder. How to do it? I can not find the proper answer in the documentation.
I only found this:

```
POST outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx

?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
            <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
                <t:ConnectingSID>
                    <t:PrimarySmtpAddress>test@test_test.onmicrosoft.com</t:PrimarySmtpAddress>
                </t:ConnectingSID>
            </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
        </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:SyncFolderHierarchy>
      <m:FolderShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
      </m:FolderShape>
      <m:SyncFolderId>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="publicfoldersroot" />
      </m:SyncFolderId>
    </m:SyncFolderHierarchy>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and the response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="1207" MinorBuildNumber="28" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <m:SyncFolderHierarchyResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <m:ResponseMessages>
                <m:SyncFolderHierarchyResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
                    <m:MessageText>The root of a folder hierarchy synchronization cannot be set to the id of a public folder. Use FindFolder to synchronize the public folder hierarchy.</m:MessageText>
                    <m:ResponseCode>ErrorInvalidOperation</m:ResponseCode>
                    <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
                    <m:SyncState/>
                    <m:IncludesLastFolderInRange>true</m:IncludesLastFolderInRange>
                </m:SyncFolderHierarchyResponseMessage>
            </m:ResponseMessages>
        </m:SyncFolderHierarchyResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As you can see it does not work.

Comment: Have you checked this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-synchronize-folders-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: as you can see the request above is the same as you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: The request to get the public folder should contain the X-AnchorMailbox value and the X-PublicFolderInformation value. For more information, please see the following link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-route-public-folder-hierarchy-requests